# javascript code partially not executed in test environment, works in production, development (Rails 3 app)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara

Rails 3

I have a list inside a form:

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
  <ul>
    <% @product.each do |p| %>
      <li id="product_<%=p.id%>">
        <div>
         <%= f.radio_button(:p_id, p.id, class: 'hidden') %>
        </div>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <%= f.submit 'submit', :id=>"submit_category", :class=>'hide' %>
<% end %>
```

I added a javascript function so that when the user clicks on the li element, the radio button is selected and the form is submitted.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('li').click(function() {
    $(this).find('input[type=radio]').attr('checked', true);
    $('#submit_category').click();
  });
</script>
```

This works perfectly in production, development, but the test environment fails: the form IS submitted, but the radio button is not selected, so I get a validation error.

My tests are done with Cucumber + Selenium + Capybara. Line of testing:

```
When /^I click on the "(.*?)" product$/ do |product_name|
  @product = Product.find_by_name(product_name)
  page.find('li', id: "product_#{@p.id}").click
end
```

Comment: I know this question is old, but is there just a validation error or do you get a error on the test itself too? I'm assuming you enabled JS on the test.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing here, but does wrapping the code  a $(function () { ..your code }) (domready) callback help?